# How to add more independent containers

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, widget, rows

I am trying to add more containers outside of this first container. I get syntax error when I use: Container() after the first container. It seems impossible to add another child in the body section as well-- I want to add 10 more containers inside the body of the app, please help. I am trying to add more containers outside of this first container. I get syntax error when I use: Container() after the first container. It seems impossible to add another child in the body section as well-- I want to add 10 more containers inside the body of the app, please help

```
body: Center(
    child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 567.0),
      color: Color(0xffffb400),
      height: 85,
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 30,
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/beer.png'),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Beer',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 10.5,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 15,
          ),
          Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 30,
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/wine.png'),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Wine',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 10.5,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 15,
          ),
          Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 30,
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/spirits.png'),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Spirits',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 10.5,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 15,
          ),
          Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 30,
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/cider.png'),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Cider',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 10.5,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 15,
          ),
          Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 30,
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/premixes.png'),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Premixes',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 10.5,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 15,
          ),
          Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 30,
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/local.png'),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Local',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 10.5,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 15,
          ),
          Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 30,
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/luxury.png'),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Luxury',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 10.5,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 15,
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 30,
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/mixes.png'),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Mixes',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 10.5,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your question and code properly.

Comment: You can use the `code Smaple` icon, the curly brackets to add a properly organized code

Comment: Apologies, I am new to stackoverflow. Let me try again

Comment: I have made the changes to my question and code

Comment: What errors do you get? Your code works for me.

Comment: Inserting a new Container(), gives me: Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found. (Documentation) Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments.

Comment: body: Center( child: Container(), Container(),), this is what i am trying to achieve. Adding another container after the one on the code

Answer (score 0):

Well it's the reusabilty of the widget, you basically want to achieve!
That is where functions come to play:

Define a paramterized function that returns widget like:

```
    Widget showItem(String name, String image) {
    return Container(child: Column(
    children: [
      CircleAvatar(
      backgroundImage: AssetImage(image)),
      Text(name),
    ]));
   }
```

Now call showItem() with passing different name and image in ListView as:

```
showItem("Beer", "assets/images/beer.png")
```

Hope it helps, Cheers